# How to hide specific categories from contributors

Tags: php

I want to hide the categories 'news','blog','main', but not 'bloggers' from contributors users only in Add New/edit post area.

I found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405507/wordpress-hide-specific-categories-from-user-role-on-the-add-new-page) which works with Members plugin:

```
add_filter('list_terms_exclusions', 'yoursite_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2);
function yoursite_list_terms_exclusions( $exclusions, $args ) {

global $pagenow;
if (in_array($pagenow,array('post.php','post-new.php')) && 
!current_user_can('see_special_cats')) {
    $exclusions = " {$exclusions} AND t.slug NOT IN ('slug-one','slug-two')";
}
return $exclusions;
}
```

They say, it works, but I don't know how to customize it. Simply adding in function.php doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to change `see_special_cats` to something fitting. As you want to exclude contributors, but allow all others, you could use `publish_posts` (See [the codex for all capabilities of contributors](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Contributor)).

Your code should be something like

```
add_filter('list_terms_exclusions', 'yoursite_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2);
function yoursite_list_terms_exclusions( $exclusions, $args ) {

    global $pagenow;
    if (in_array($pagenow,array('post.php','post-new.php')) && 
!current_user_can('publish_posts')) {
        $exclusions = " {$exclusions} AND t.slug NOT IN ('news', 'blog', 'main')";
    }
    return $exclusions;
}
```

Keep in mind that you might have to adjust the slugs, which I've just assumed are `news`, `blog` and `main`.

Comment: I have the categories with these slugs. Now I must add 'publish_posts' as a custom capability for contributors?... I just want to hide all other categories instead of 'bloggers'.

Comment: No, this is working for those who cannot `publish_posts`, so you shouldn't add that capability to contributors, as it'll affect only contributors (and readers, but those cannot add posts). If you have other categories besides `bloggers`, you'll have to include those - it might be easier to generate the array of slugs in PHP in that case.